# Creating several heatmaps with seaborn overlapped from the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn, heatmap

The dataframe is the next one:

[image: Dataframe]

```py
numpy = np.zeros((df.x.max()+1, df.y.max()+1))
numpy[df.x, df.y] = df.Value
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(numpy.T, cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False).get_figure().savefig("world_heatmap.png", dpi=300)

numpy1= np.zeros((df.x.max()+1, df.y.max()+1))
numpy1[df.x, df.y] = df.Appearance_percentage
probheatmap = sns.heatmap(numpy1.T, cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False).get_figure().savefig("world_probheatmap.png", dpi=300)

numpy2 = np.zeros((df.x.max()+1, df.y.max()+1))
numpy2[df.x, df.y] = df.Few_clouds
bestzonesheatmap = sns.heatmap(numpy2.T, cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False).get_figure().savefig("world_bestzonesheatmap.png", dpi=300)
```

With all this I have obtained this:

[image: Hm1]

[image: Hm2]

[image: Hm3]

As you can see is like each heatmap is like overlapping the other one. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!!!! <3

PD: Heatmaps are OK, what you can see next to each of them is wrong.

Comment: **Add code, errors, and data as text**, not screenshots because [SO Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**.

Comment: Just add `plt.clf()` ("clear current figure") after each call to `savefig` to start the next plot with a blank canvas